# Problem when Adding Rigidbody to Object Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my scene, I instantiate several cubes (they didn't have any rigidbody),

When each of them trigger with the player I add rigidbody to it (from the player script below).

It works and the object get the rigidbody, but I got a lot of warnings in the console like this:

> Can't add component 'Rigidbody' to Cube (87) because such a component is already added to the game object!
>
> Can't add component 'Rigidbody' to Cube (88) because such a component is already added to the game object!
>
> Can't add component 'Rigidbody' to Cube (89) because such a component is already added to the game object!

How can I avoid those warnings? because they'll **hurt the performance**!

**Script:**

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Cube"))
    {
        other.gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test if the other object doesn't yet have a rigidbody by checking if `other.rigidbody == null`:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Cube") && other.rigidbody == null)
    {
        other.gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
}
```